# Send form input value to URL

Tags: html, forms, url

I have a simple search form:

```
<form method="get" action="">
<input id="search" placeholder="Search" type="search" name="search"></input>
</form>
```

I want to get the value from "search" and have it show up in the url like this:

```
http://domain.ca/blog/search/searchterm
```

So if a visitor searches for "kubrick", they'll get a URL like:

```
http://domain.ca/blog/search/kubrick
```

I can't use PHP. Is there a Javascript solution?

Comment: Is your PHP script allow these type of permalinks?

Comment: Yes, it does allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try a javascript redirection for onsubmit event.
To avoid empty searches, use the attribute "required" for the input.

Example:

```
<form onsubmit="window.location = 'http://domain.ca/blog/search/' + search.value; return false;">
<input id="search" placeholder="Search" type="search" name="search"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: As soon as I click on that field it submits it, before I can input anything.

Comment: Sorry, wrong code. Changed the event to onsubmit and added the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Pedro did an awesome thing here, but including
required input tag is also smooth,as it checks that a user is not making an empty search

Comment: Your answer should better be a comment.