# Coeigniter Url : separating variables with slashes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter for developing my website.When submitting form Iam variables separated with ? and &. I want variables separated with slashes like below.

Now getting like this

```html
http://example.com/controller/method?id=22&sd=31
```

I want an url like below

```html
http://example.com/controller/method/22/31
```

Html Code is given below

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>controller/method" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
<select id="id" name="id" class="selectcl  form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Pick Your place" > 
<option value="22" >22</option>  
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="sd" id="sd" placeholder="Enter details"  title="please choose">//getting values here by autocomplete
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <button type="submit" class="btn find" value="submit" ></i>Start </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Tried URI Routing and below

```html
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
```

Please help  me to find a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can modify the way a get form serializes its data in the url. Routing wouldn't really change anything.

Comment: Show us where this `http://example.com/controller/method?id=22&sd=31` is generated in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your form method `get` to `post`

```
<form id="form" action="<?php echo base_url('controller/method');?>" method="post">
```

add following jquery in the page.

```
$(function(){
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){        
        e.preventDefault();       
        var id = $.trim($('#id').val());
        var sd = $.trim($('#sd').val());
        if(id.length > 0 && sd.length > 0){
            var url_string  = new URL($('#form').attr('action'));
            window.location.href = url_string.href.concat(((url_string.href.endsWith('/')) ? '' : '/'),id,'/',encodeURIComponent(sd));
        } 
    });    
});
```

Comment: now the url is like http://example.com/22/31, Controller and methods are missing @Anfath Hifans

Comment: have you passed from your like this .? `<?php echo base_url('controller/method');?>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the value through URL, Try the below link:

[Send form input value to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601098/send-form-input-value-to-url?answertab=oldest#tab-top)