# How to create a link incorporating user input from the input box

Tags: html, webforms

I am looking to interface with a web system, containing articles defined by unique codes.

e.g. **Order System** contains orders **ORD001, ORD002**

The Order System contains a website, where each order has its own unique page.

The public url to view `ORD001` would be `www.sampleorders.com/ORD001`, `ORD002` would be `www.sampleorders.com/ORD002`

I would like to prevent the user with an input box, where they can enter their order number, and be routed to the correct web address.

[image: Sample interface where the user could enter order number]

Is there an easy way to concatenate a predefined string (`www.sampleorders.com/`) and Form user input (`ORD001`), using html and javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601098/send-form-input-value-to-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript and/or jquery for that.

try passing this post id (in the url) in the snippet below.

```js
$("input#post_id").on("change", function(){ // Whenever this field changes

  var post_id = $("input#post_id").val(); // Get the value of the field
  
  $("a#link").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + post_id); // Update the href in the link to match the id inserted in the input field
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Which post would you load ?</label>

<br>

<input id="post_id" type="text">

<a id="link" href="#">Go</a>
```