# How to create a link that concatenates the user input in HTML

Tags: html, jquery, url, concatenation, customization

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- $("input#post_id").on("change", function(){ // Whenever this field changes

  var post_id = $("input#post_id").val(); // Get the value of the field

  $("a#link").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + post_id); // Update the href in the link to match the id inserted in the input field

}); -->



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Enter the DP ID below </label>

<br>

<input id="post_id" type="text">

<a id="link" href='https://www.google.com/search?'+post_id.value>Click to redirect</a>

</body>
</html>
```

[How to create a link incorporating user input from the input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663246/how-to-create-a-link-incorporating-user-input-from-the-input-box/67264700#67264700)

I'm trying to attempt a similar mechanism but as I'm too new to HTML, I'm unable to quickly club it with jquery.

Appreciate any help! Thanks!

My sample query - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPZYOB9C4JFW

When I initially tried this approach the url generated had [ input object HTML ] something like this instead of the user input string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Appreciate if you can brief a little more

Comment: Please post your code here, not at an external site.

Comment: `post_id` should be `post_id.value`

Comment: 'code'


<!-- $("input#post_id").on("change", function(){ // Whenever this field changes

  var post_id = $("input#post_id").val(); // Get the value of the field

  $("a#link").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + post_id); // Update the href in the link to match the id inserted in the input field

}); ->


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Enter the DP ID below </label>

<br>

<input id="post_id" type="text">

<a id="link" href='https://www.google.com/search?'+post_id>Click to redirect</a>

Comment: You're never calling the jQuery code, it's not in a `<script>`

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Thanks! I've added to the question.
I've replaced the post_id with post_id.value and I see the output didn't change.

To answer your question 2 about jQuery - I've unsure how to call it. I've gone through posts and identified a similar post and tried to copy paste the input from that post, the question is mentioned in the post.

Comment: Why is your jQuery code in a `<!-- ... -->` instead of `<script>...</script>`?

Comment: variables aren't expanded inside HTML attributes. `+post_id.value` doesn't add to the `href` URL.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have `<script>` tag and jQuery document ready tag `$(function() {` to make it work.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("input#post_id").on("change", function(){ // Whenever this field changes

    var post_id = $("input#post_id").val(); // Get the value of the field
    
    $("a#link").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + post_id); // Update the href in the link to match the id inserted in the input field

  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the jQuery code inside a `<script>` tag after the one that ooads the jQuery library.

Also put the code inside `$(document).ready()` so it runs after the HTML is fully loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#post_id").on("change", function() { // Whenever this field changes
      var post_id = $("input#post_id").val(); // Get the value of the field

      $("a#link").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" + post_id); // Update the href in the link to match the id inserted in the input field

    });
  });  
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Enter the DP ID below </label>
  <br>
  <input id="post_id" type="text">
  <a id="link" href='https://www.google.com/search?'>Click to redirect</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for modifying that.
From the current code, it redirects to stack overflow while I understand I need to change the href in the line --> $("a#link") is there a way where I can recall the user input multiple times for different URLs?
Link the body of the code - I'm trying to put it as an input to google.com

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a full lesson on writing JavaScript and jQuery code. You need to read tutorials.